# Is the first argument to pthread_create function a thread handler

Tags: c, pthreads

The Linux man page defines the pthread_create function as

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                          void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

What's this pointer to the pthread_t used for? Can we say it's a thread handler?

Comment: if anything it is a pointer to the variable storing the thread **handle**, not **handler**.

Answer (score 0):

From the [manpage of pthread_create](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html):

> See [pthread_self(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_self.3.html) for further information on the thread ID returned in `*thread` by `pthread_create()`.

You can also call it a handle (not handler).

You can use that ID for `pthread_join`.